# What caused humanity's extinction at the end of of A.I. Artificial Intelligence?

Tags: a.i.-artificial-intelligence

The advanced mechas said the human race was extinguished. How did that happen? Because the Earth froze? Weren't there any humans living in space stations or moon colonies?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Global warming followed by a catastrophic ice age.

The initial voice-over describes a world in which runaway global warming has already resulted in the deaths of hundreds of millions of people and a dramatic loss of coastal land. Those that remained were only able to survive (and indeed to thrive) because of drastic population control and the presence of a new 'slave class' of artificial people.

> Those were the years after the ice caps had melted because of the
> greenhouse gases, and the oceans had risen to drown so many cities
> along all the shorelines of the world. Amsterdam, Venice, New York,
> forever lost. Millions of people were displaced, climate became
> chaotic. Hundreds of millions of people starved in poorer countries.
> **Elsewhere a high degree of prosperity survived when most governments
> in the developed world introduced legal sanctions to strictly license
> pregnancies. Which is why robots, who were never hungry and did not
> consume resources beyond that of their first manufacture, were so
> essential an economic link in the chain mail of society.”**
>
> <sub><sup>[AI: Artificial Intelligence - Opening Scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BROvLBcFfWQ)</sup></sub>

In the final scenes we see the ultimate result of the loss of the ice caps; extreme melting (and the flooding of the cities) followed by a new ice age, freezing the melted water and encapsulating the cities in ice.

---

When Aldiss described Kubrick's vision of the film's ending, he noted that there were three key elements that he was keen to preserve at all costs;

> *...Global warming, the eventual triumph of the robots and the Blue
> Fairy.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Kubrick's Story, Spielberg's Film: A.I. Artificial Intelligence](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Kubricks-Story-Spielbergs-Film-I/dp/1442278188)</sup></sub>

and

> *According to Brian Aldiss, the directors plan for A.J. emphasized the
> planetary alterations and eventual extinctions that global warming
> would gradually cause. The catastrophe would not be a sudden
> incineration but a steady progress **from the chaotic conditions of a
> hotter planet to a life-destroying ice age.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Kubrick's Story, Spielberg's Film: A.I. Artificial Intelligence](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Kubricks-Story-Spielbergs-Film-I/dp/1442278188)</sup></sub>

Comment: Couldn't humanity survive by living in underground shelters
or "noe's arks" ?

Comment: @Tito - In theory, yes. In reality, and over a span of a thousand years it would only take a few failed heaters or air-processors for each and every "ark" to fail one by one. Note that with current tech, scientists were unable to stay inside a [biodome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biosphere_2) (one with unlimited sunlight) for a single year without narrowly avoiding starving to death and choking on their own CO2

Comment: Humany had already survived an Ice Age, 10 thousands years ago, by living inside caves. It wouldn't be much more easier to survive another Ice Age,
with today's technology?

Comment: @Tito - You have to remember that this film was written and directed by people who've entirely bought into the whole "*global warming will kill us all unless we do something about it immediately*" rhetoric. That's quite literally the message that Kubrick was trying to hammer home to audiences.

Comment: @Tito, there are ice ages and there are ice ages.  Compare the [Last Glacial Maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Glacial_Maximum) with  (to take an extreme case) [Snowball Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowball_Earth).  Also, [some people think](http://io9.gizmodo.com/close-calls-three-times-when-the-human-race-barely-esc-1730998797?IR=T) that humanity very nearly *didn't* survive the last glaciation.  Not too much of a stretch to suppose that this time we weren't as fortunate.

Comment: ... on the other hand, the fact that the *robots* survived but were unable to save humanity strikes me as somewhat implausible.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - The robots appear to be self-sustaining (nuclear?)

Comment: @Valorum, sure, but they should still need routine maintenance, which requires an industrial base.  Except that I've just realized that the protagonist had to survive the entire period without maintenance in order for the plot to work, so I guess this comes under [Acceptable Breaks from Reality](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AcceptableBreaksFromReality).

Comment: @HarryJohnston - Robots repairing other robots? [How perverse...](https://youtu.be/Xr9s6-tuppI?t=3s)

Comment: @Valorum [Sickening...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkh0_grCreI)

Comment: @HarryJohnston probably because they weren't programmed to save mankind. They didn't know what to do. It's just like God asking us to help save him. What could we do?

Comment: By the way, that ice age could have killed all the plants and animals on Earth and the humans didn't have stock food for a thousands of years period.

Comment: @Tito, if you've got a solid industrial base, you should be able to grow food hydroponically.  And the robots don't need to know what to do; we'd *tell* them what to do.  But if you assume the robots didn't need maintenance (as suggested by David's survival) then there's no problem.  Alternatively, you might suppose that only just enough of an industrial base survived for the robots to keep themselves going, not enough to support humanity.